# Laravel Ardent not letting me save my User

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ardent

I started a project last night in Laravel and am using Ardent and Entrust packages to help make my User model more secure and easy to use.  I have set everything up but am not able to seed my database.  No errors are thrown but it is definitely not saving to my database.

This is my User model.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends Ardent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use HasRole;

    public static $rules = array(
        'username'              => 'required|alpha_num|between:6,18|unique:users',
        'email'                 => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'password'              => 'required|alpha_num|min:8',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|min:8',
        'first_name'            => 'alpha',
        'last_name'             => 'alpha',
        'city'                  => 'alpha',
        'state'                 => 'alpha',
        'rate'                  => 'numeric',
        'profile_pic'           => 'image',
        'commitment'            => 'string'
    );

    public static $passwordAttributes  = array('password');

    public $autoHydrateEntityFromInput = true;

    public $forceEntityHydrationFromInput = true;

    public $autoPurgeRedundantAttributes = true;

    public $autoHashPasswordAttributes = true;

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

This is my `users` schema in my migrations.

```
Schema::create(
    'users',
    function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('state', 2)->nullable();
        $table->string('zip', 9)->nullable();
        $table->float('rate', 10, 2)->nullable();
        $table->boolean('listed')->default(false);
        $table->string('profile_pic')->nullable();
        $table->string('commitment')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    }
);
```

Lastly, here is my seed data.

```
$admin = User::create(
    array(
         'username'              => 'admin',
         'email'                 => 'admin@example.com',
         'password'              => 'admin',
         'password_confirmation' => 'admin',
         'first_name'            => 'Admin',
         'last_name'             => 'User',
         'city'                  => 'Cincinnati',
         'state'                 => 'OH',
         'zip'                   => '45243'
    )
);

User::create(
    array(
         'username'              => 'user',
         'email'                 => 'user@example.com',
         'password'              => 'user',
         'password_confirmation' => 'user',
         'first_name'            => 'Normal',
         'last_name'             => 'User'
    )
);
```

I have narrowed it down to the fact that I'm extending Ardent in my User model, but I don't know why.

Comment: In  `DatabaseSeeder.php`, you don't have  `this->call('UsersTableSeeder');` commented or anything?

Comment: No it's definitely uncommented.  The thing I can't figure out is if I change the `extends Ardent` back to `extends Eloquent`, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  My seeds weren't passing validation.  Because when it fails Ardent stores the errors in a `MessageBag` instance in the model, I wasn't seeing the errors.  I had to print those errors out in my seeds to see.  Such a dumb mistake.  Hopefully others see this and don't make that mistake!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. How did you print your MessageBag errors to the terminal when running your seeds?

Comment: You can get the error MessageBag by calling `$errors = $user->errors();`.  Then, I would call `dd($errors)`.  This will run `var_dump` on the `errors` variable and then `die` on the application.  It will dump the variable contents to the terminal screen.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you just insert the seed data directly into the database, you dont actually use your model:

```
$user = array (
         'username'              => 'admin',
         'email'                 => 'admin@example.com',
         'password'              => Hash::make('admin'),
         'first_name'            => 'Admin',
         'last_name'             => 'User',
         'city'                  => 'Cincinnati',
         'state'                 => 'OH',
         'zip'                   => '45243');

DB::table('users')->insert($user);
```

Comment: It can be done either way.  Since I have already made my models, I can do it this way.  Even if I didn't do it this way, I would still have this problem.  I tried to insert a user in a route to test to make sure it wasn't my seed and it didn't work in the route either.  So something is wrong when I use the Ardent class.

Comment: in that case - seed the database with some users - and just work on another example of the error in your routes. Trying to diagnose the problem with seeds from artisan is going to be difficult. Can you update a user? Or is it only on insertion of a new user?

Comment: This was certainly the simplest way that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late and you've solved this, but thought I'd add a note for others...

Your password validation rules state that the password has to be a minimum of 8 characters, while your seed data only had 5 ('admin')

Comment: admin is five characters

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me, and I realized that my db didn't have value I was storing. 
Instead of throwing and exception it just went blank and did not execute the next piece of code. It's weird, but that may be a solution.